# How to handle can-connect errors correcly when connecting to a RESTful API

Tags: javascript, rest, mvvm, promise, canjs

I've managed to load data and to save data. But cannot understand the error handling scheme needed.
When everything goes fine I receive the same object in that was sent but with an extra attribute `_saving` (false).

When something goes wrong, for instance try to store a string instead of a number, I'll get:

1. Bad request (error on the console, don't want that)
2. The response object (might be usefull to show an error)
3. "Uncaught (in promise)" error

#### Example:

Code:

```
this.save()
    .then(function(result) {
    console.log('ok1', result);
}).catch(function() {
    console.log('errorHandler1');
});
```

- OK:

  - [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogoc1opcmh6w23q/Screenshot%202016-09-24%2010.35.08.png?dl=1]
- Error:

  - [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hufs2b68t8bqfhl/Screenshot%202016-09-24%2010.36.02.png?dl=1]

I've been trying to use catch on promises, following this guidelines:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch
but had no luck at all.

This should should work buy just changing `p1.then` to `thisObjectThatIWantToSave.save.then` but it didn't.

```
p1.then(function(value) {
    console.log(value); // "Success!"
    throw 'oh, no!';
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
}).then(function(){
    console.log('after a catch the chain is restored');
}, function () {
    console.log('Not fired due to the catch');
});
```

Again, it still stores the information when the data is correct, the problem I see is that I don't have the tools to decide when was the data correctly stored or not and to avoid triggering errors that can be correctly handled.

#### I'm using

- canjs v3.0.0-pre.11
- a restful API provided by feathers

Comment: What do you mean "error handling scheme needed"?  If `_saving` is being sent, this is probably a bug.  Can you create an issue here: https://github.com/canjs/can-connect and we'll look at it this week?

Comment: "error handling scheme needed" => maybe should have been: "way to handle errors"

Comment: Issue posted: https://github.com/canjs/can-connect/issues/153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error handling ...

> Bad request (error on the console, don't want that)

There's no way of preventing the error on the console.  This is something chrome does.

> The response object (might be usefull to show an error)

You can read the `reason` for the rejection in can-stache like `{{promise.reason}}`.

> "Uncaught (in promise)" error

I'm not sure why this is being thrown as clearly, your `catch` is being hit. If you change it to:

```
this.save()
    .then(function(result) {
    console.log('ok1', result);
},function() {
    console.log('errorHandler1');
});
```

Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: While using a simple canjs app/page it does not prevent the error to be triggered. But when I use it within a donejs project (using can 2.3.27) it works, and I can successfully detect the error.